# How can I convert a 2d Number array into a 2d String array?

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion

I'm really new to java or programming, so i have a "basic" quesion (I guess). I have this code, which generates me an array of numbers. I want to convert that into an array of strings. Can someone please fix my code?

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Number[][] values = new Number[10][12];
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
                values[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000) / 100000;

                System.out.print(values[i][j] + " ; ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you still need the array of `Number`s afterwards? If not, just convert the number to a string as soon as you generate it an declare `values` as `String[][]`. As an aside, why use `Number` when `double` is more than adequate?

Comment: Yes, I need the numbers afterwards. And with the doubles / numbers array, thank you for that hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious way:

```
public static String[][] convert(Number[][] numbers) {
        String[][] result = new String[numbers.length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i ++) {
            Number[] row = numbers[i];
            result[i] = new String[row.length];
            for(int j = 0; j < row.length; j ++) {
                result[i][j] = row[j] == null ? null : row[j].toString();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Less obvious way:

```
public static String[][] convert(Number[][] numbers) {
        return Arrays.stream(numbers)
                .map(row -> Arrays.stream(row).map(n -> String.valueOf(n)).toArray(String[]::new))
                .toArray(String[][]::new);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do I add this to my class? Just as a second method or do I have to change something?

Comment: Yes, add method to your class and call it like `String [][] strValues = convert(values);`

Comment: Do I have to rename it? Cause when I copy & paste it and than change the line to "String [][] strValues = convert(values);", I get some error messages. I'm really new to java so sorry for that stupid quesions.

Comment: No need to rename, it should be enough to place method inside your class and make sure it's static when calling it from main().

Comment: Okay thank you, but one last question: how are these two methods connected?

Comment: What do mean by connected? Both methods in this answer perform same functionality but use different logic. First one just iterates over 2d array and creates string array of same length. Second one uses java streams and maps number array to string array in a functional way. You need only one of them (which one is your choice).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use String array instead of Number array. When setting the element, use `String.valueOf(YOUR_NUMBER)`

Comment: So I write String [][] values = new String[12][10]; and than? Where do I use your String.valueOf?

Comment: In here just add:
`values[i][j] = String.valueOf(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000) / 100000);